# I have to design own php file and set the template file to my page in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I have to design own php file and set the template to my page in wordpress. but in admin site, my own template is not visible in drop down list

Answer (score 0):

Have your theme files just after the directory ?

Answer (score 0):

Put below code top on the custom-template.php(custom template php file)

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: My Custom Page
*/
```

custom template php file path should be

```
/wp-content/themes/your-theme/custom-template.php(custom template php file)
```